# Can't select text with touchpad

Tags: mouse, touchpad

I have Acer v3-371 with Linux Mint 17.2 and I have some problems with touchpad.

I don't have right touchpad button, it only works if I turn on in settings that two fingers on touchpad are recognized as right button. This makes problem that I'm unnable to perform any action which requires two fingers on touchpad like selecting text or relocating icons on desktop.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any action which requires *two* fingers on the touchpad. Do you mean "double-tap means right-click"?

In that case, I see two possibilities:
(a) Do a double-tap, but do *not* take the finger off the touchpad after the second tap. This means: Down-Up-Down-Move instead of Down-Up-Down-Up-Down-Move.
(b) Just push down with your index (or other) finger, then use your thumb to push down the physical left-mouse button to select text. This requires a bit of training, though. Since I disable tapping altogether, this is what I use.